# How to put a csv data string in an array using PHP?

Tags: php

We have split up a CSV file into individual lines and those lines have been stored into a database.  Normally I would use fgetcsv to import each line of a file into an array when it is imported.  However, since the CSV data is now stored in the database, I cannot use that function anymore.  Is there an equivalent function that would import a single csv line as a string and then break it into and array?

I realize I could just explode based on "," but there are some other issues with doing that like the way Excel uses quotations around some fields, etc.

Comment: "We have split up a CSV file into individual lines and those lines have been stored into a database." **YOU'RE DOING IT WRONG.** Databases are for storing structured data; you should split it up (and normalize it) before storing in the database.

Comment: We're using the database as a queue for later processing.  It is really just temporary storage, not long term usage.

Comment: It's getting pretty old having people always comment that a denormalized database is inherently wrong.  Yes, you should normalize for most standard applications, but it's simply not always the case; knee-jerk reactions are not the solution, critical thought is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php

Agree with previous comment though, you probably shouldn't be putting CSV data in your database unless there's a compelling reason to do so (and there are some).

Comment: Thanks!  I should have been able to find that myself.  Sorry about that.